# vb.net passing a value that will tell a function to use it's default value

Tags: vb.net

There are so many q/a with the default parameters that I can't find easily what I am looking for. Not that I can't solve this with one (or more) if ... then ... end if, but I wanted to find out if there is (are) a better approach with this (simpler, inline for ie by using IIf). So my question is this: 
Is there any keyword that can tell called function that it should use default value instead of that keyword. For example:

```
  Public Function A(Optional ConnectionString As String = Nothing) As String
    A = B(IIf(ConnectionString Is Nothing, "keyword", ConnectionString))
  End Function

  Public Function B(Optional ConnectionString As String = "Something") As String
    'do something
  End Function
```

Reason why I need this is just for cleaner and simpler code. Sometimes there are more conditions inside those functions and nesting more if(s) can make code to cumbersome.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I am working now like this (don't want this as solution):

```
  Public Function A(Optional ConnectionString As String = Nothing) As String
    if ConnectionString Is Nothing then
      A = B()
    else
      A = B(ConnectionString)
    end if
  End Function
```

So, can I write something like this (I want this as possibility):

```
  Public Function A(Optional ConnectionString As String = Nothing) As String
      A = B(if(ConnectionString, default))
    end if
  End Function
```

Where default will fail back to default value of parameter in B function.

**EDIT 2**

I have tried to assign the connection string as default for the optional parameter in the function A, but it doesn't work somehow, so I have opted to look for the solution I wrote about above in my question.
[image: Optional parameter here doesn't work, look at this picture]

Comment: Could what you want be achieved by passing a different number of parameters? [Overloading Methods in Visual Basic .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973896.aspx).

Comment: yes, sure it could be done with different no. of parameters, but I wanted to avoid using if...then...else...end if, thanks

Comment: Are you seeking [If Operator Called with Two Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator#if-operator-called-with-two-arguments) that is commonly referred to as the _null coalescing operator_?

Comment: Note that connections strings are usually best stored in a config file so that you don't have to recompile the program if they change.

Comment: @TnTinMn thanks for pointing me to if(,) operator, really useful thing, I would like to use it as A = B(if(ConnectionString, default)) that will solve this the best! I think now I should write this to Microsoft so they can implement 'default' in the language

Comment: @AndrewMorton , I am building a page that will use connection stringS from a web config and execute some queries based on selected connection string, but in the core set functions (that are already in the system) default conn string must exists otherwise it will break everything. so if conn string is not passed from the page level function i have to omit it so it takes default in the core functions, but I want this with less ifs if possible

Comment: @DejanDozet I recommend that also you put the default connection string in web.config to keep things consistent. Then, use the *name* of the connection string in `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(CONNSTRNAME).ConnectionString` to retrieve the required value. Then you can have `Optional ConnectionStringName As String = "Default"`, assuming you named the default one as "Default".

Comment: @AndrewMorton, thanks Andrew, and I did it for B function ("Something"), things are more complicated for A function where I can't put the same value or I could but that is another question, look, that A function is WebInvoke, and I don't know why setting default value for WebInvoke doesn't work, it always fail to nothing

Answer (score 0):

---

### Edit

Funny thing that you can almost exactly do this. Took me long enough to understand what you wanted, though!!

```
Public Function A(Optional ConnectionString As String = Nothing) As String
    A = If(ConnectionString is Nothing, B(), B(ConnectionString))
End Function
```

---

### Original answer below this line

You can have more than one overload for the same function call.

```
Public Sub Example()
    Example("DefaultValue")
End Sub

Public Sub Example(ByVal value As String)
    'do things
End Sub
```

In this example you can call either do:

```
Example()    'This will use the default value by calling the other sub with an overload you already defines as "default"
```

or

```
Example("SomeString")    'This is your normal overloaded Sub
```

You can have as many as you want of those as long as they are not impossible to distinguish.

Have fun!

Comment: Oh, and by the way, an optional parameter WILL use the default value if you don't specify a value. It's that easy.

Comment: yes, I agree, but I don't know if I am being clear here, but my idea was not to use if...then...else...end if and I wanted to use inline Iif statement to check if a parameter has a correct value (for ie not nothing). Of course this is not a real problem, anyway I am using now twice as much code and if this could be solved with extra keyword my code would me much more clearer. Thanks

Comment: Is French your first language? You can use french with me if it's easier for you. I'm not sure if I get what you mean, but here's a thing I noticed from your example code: You could call both function without using a parameter (because they are optional). Like, you could call `A()` and the parameter would automatically be `Nothing` because that's the default value you entered. Same thing with function b: you can call it `B()` and the parameter would then automatically be `"Something"` as if you had called it `B("Something")`. That's how Optional works, no need for If statements.

Comment: again I agree, but notice that the first function has default = nothing (which can't be something -> I can't change default to be something) and the second has default = something (which can't be nothing -> I can't work with nothing as connection string has to exists anyway) that all is because of the nature of those functions, that said I have to check if ConnectionString (A) is nothing and then call B function without ConnectionString (which will force B function to take it's default parameter), or to pass that ConnectionString as parameter of function B. thanks

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The `Optional` value is meant as a fallback for the case where there's no value used in the call. An empty string is not the same thing as no value, so I think that you'll have to keep the If statement.

Comment: please see my EDIT section, this is only my wish, but I don't think this exists in vb.net

Comment: I edited my answer, it might just suits your needs. It's still an If statement, but much cleaner, kinda like what you wrote in your edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate all your help, but I was hoping that there is something, like some keyword that will signal for function to use it's default value for that parameter, it is not so unreasonable to have, isn't it? I mean there are many "less useful" things that still exists in VB.net, so why this feature is not available? I really don't know....

Comment: The thing is... if the function is called without a parameter, why not putting the B default parameter right away instead of `Nothing` ?? It'll end up the same, but with one less function.

Comment: Thank you for your effort again, I really appreciate it, please take a look at my second edit, that is real A function (a webinvoke that can't have a default value event if you put it there, it still shows Nothing in debug mode)

Comment: If it was called `selectFromTable("tableName", 999, Nothing)` it will actually use `Nothing` instead of the default parameter, that's normal. If it's called `selectFromTable("tableName", 999)`, it should fall back on the default value you specified (ICSRCOnnectionString is this case). Is it behaving this way? If not, that's weird and unexpected.